# how to analyze adb command responses/results

Tags: android, adb, android-broadcast

I am trying to analyze the response of some adb commands:
 - Enter (and exit airplane mode)

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
```

The first line doesn't respond anything in the cli output.  The second provides me:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

I see on my android phone it went to airplane mode but I am trying to evaluate if the command was successful without visual.  What does "result=0" mean?  Even when I execute a broadcast with misspelled action it returned the same result.  Can anyone help me understand?
Thank you for you help in advance.  I am new to android programming and I need little help understanding.

Comment: The broadcast will be successful no matter what you put in the action. After all, it's a broadcast. Just like a radio-broadcast will be successful, regardless of whether anyone has a radio turned on.

Comment: It's like you shot a gun by pulling the gun's trigger. Then you are trying to find out whether you hit a target by analyzing the current trigger position. In other words if you want to check whether you were successful in changing the AIRPLANE_MODE state - just check the current state.

Comment: Current state?  Which command is that?  I know its not "adb devices".